# ESXi, how do I set the IP address on NIC's?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, nic

Sorry in advance I am brand new to ESXi and VSphere 5.0. I just installed a second NIC into one of our ESXi boxes and I was wondering how I set the IP address of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bit off topic, but does anyone know of a good book I could get to learn ESXi/vSphere?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure that either in the esxi console, or more likely using the vsphere client. Host -> Configuration -> Network, depending on whether it is for your host or for your vm network, or just add it to the network teaming.

Comment: When I go to edit it in vsphere, I go Host -> Config -> Network ->Network Adapters Tab -> select network adapter-> edit

The only option it gives me is to set the speed/duplex

Comment: go to networking instead of network adapters, either add networking to create a new vswitch, or edit an existing vswitch if you are adding the nic to an existing one.

Comment: Sorry, I did go to "Networking" though I said "Network" above.
I click the Properties button right above the Physical Adapters, click the Network Adapters tab and try to edit my 2nd adapter. Only thing that pops up is duplex.

Comment: After you open "Properties" you stay in the "ports" tab.  You can change the ip addresses in "Manage Network" in the list there.  Just select it and click the "Edit..." button.

Answer (score 1):

Used to be on ESXi you could go to the console and set it under networking after logging in as an administrative/root user, without having to use vsphere interface. This may have changed in five, I've only used 3.x and 4.x.

Probably can also alter from the configuration tab for the host in vsphere, but like I said I haven't used vSphere 5, so the interface may have changed.

Comment: Within ESXi, under the management network settings it has Network Adapters as well as IP Configuration.

Network Adapters: Can only enable or disable adapters.
IP Configuration: Can only set the IP address for the machine, not the adapters.

Comment: Try looking from the host console and see what is configured under networking.

Answer (score 1):

Hold up! The first question is - why do you need to set an IP address on the card in the first place?

Generally, only kernel adapters need an IP, and this is set at the vSwitch level, not the card level.

So, if you are planning on just adding this new adapter to an existing vSwitch to provide redundancy and load-balancing, you do not need to IP it.

If you are going to use it in a new vSwitch for guest OS traffic, that too does not need an IP.

If you are going to add a second vSwitch for a vKernel function however (such as an iSCSI connection or a vMotion configuration), then you configure that IP address at the time you add the new vSwitch in the server configuration.

If you can give more details, I might be able to clarify further...

Comment: So, I am interning at a library. We have a staff and a public network. The VM (only one at this point on that machine) needs to have access to both networks through seperate NIC's. I wasn't sure if it would work if I just set the IP in the VM.

Sorry If I am going about this the wrong way...still learning.

Answer (score 0):

In vSphere go to config->networking->properties of vswitch (or create a new vswitch->vmkerkenel port (or a a new vmkernel port)->edit and you should see the IP settings tab